# How to get the two pictures aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
\node at (0,-2.25){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]` for both `tikzpicture`s, that will place the origin on the baseline.  Another option is to place both diagrams in the same `tikzpicture` environment, and enclose the second one in `\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]  .. \end{scope}`

Answer (score 5):

Well, to visualize the difference between both images I added `\fbox` to your pictures to get them printed in a frame:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
\node at (0,-2.25){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
} 
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture} % <=================================================
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

As you can see (red  arrows in screenshot) the height of both images is different. Now let us have a look into your code:

First image:

```
\node at (0,-2.25){$D$};
```

Second image:

```
\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
```

If you choose the same value, for example `-2.5` for both images the picture are aligned ...

See the changed MWE to value `-2.5`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}

\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
\node at (0,-2.5){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
} 
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture} % <=================================================
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result 2]

and without the added `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
\node at (0,-2.5){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} % <=================================================
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: what change in without \fbox

Comment: @PolineSandra See the x axis of both images: they are on the same height, so aligned images as wished ... The command `\fbox` was only to visualize the difference of both images, with -2.5 there is no difference ...

Answer (score 5):

As *Torbjørn T* pointed out in his commentary, it is sufficient to place the baseline of each figure at the origin `[baseline={(0,0)}]`.

Correction of the placement of the C and D labels as noticed by @Mensch:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2)node[below]{$D$} -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
%\node at (0,-2.25){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2)node[below]{$C$} -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
%\node at (0,-2.5){$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Voting down deserves an explanation. Without explanation this has no meaning other than gratuitous hostility.

Comment: Hm, the `D` and `C` have different distance to the line above. Looks not very good, I think ...

Answer (score 3):

In the following MWE I have changed the y value of the `\node` in the marked line from `2.5` to `2.25`. With this change, the x axes of the two plots are aligned, as well as the labels of the y axes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
  \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
  \draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
  \node at (0,-2.25){$D$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{}(2,0);
  \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
  \draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
  \node at (0,-2.25){$C$}; %<-----
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```